# Error in PySpark trying to run Word2Vec example

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark, word2vec

I'm trying to run the very simple example for Word2Vec given in the documentation here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/feature.html#Word2Vec

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sent = ("a b " * 100 + "a c " * 10).split(" ")
doc = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(sent,), (sent,)], ["sentence"])
model = Word2Vec(vectorSize=5, seed=42, inputCol="sentence", outputCol="model").fit(doc)
model.getVectors().show()
model.findSynonyms("a", 2).show()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e57e9f694961> in <module>()
      5 sent = ("a b " * 100 + "a c " * 10).split(" ")
      6 doc = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(sent,), (sent,)], ["sentence"])
----> 7 model = Word2Vec(vectorSize=5, seed=42, inputCol="sentence", outputCol="model").fit(doc)
      8 model.getVectors().show()
      9 model.findSynonyms("a", 2).show()

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vectorSize'
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: It's failing because you are using the wrong package. You are trying to run the Word2Vec on a DataFrame (ml package) using the mllib package that runs on RDDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to documentation from `ml` but importing from the `mllib` package. In `mllib` `Word2Vec` doesn't take any parameters in `__init__`.
Did you intend:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------+
|word|              vector|
+----+--------------------+
|   a|[-0.3511952459812...|
|   b|[0.29077222943305...|
|   c|[0.02315592765808...|
+----+--------------------+

+----+-------------------+
|word|         similarity|
+----+-------------------+
|   b|0.29255685145799626|
|   c|-0.5414068302988307|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: I intend whichever one works! I've now tried several permutations (ml/mllib and with or w/o arguments), and none seem to work. Suggestions?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, when importing from `ml`, I can construct the Word2Vec without any issue.

Comment: Can you run >> model.findSynonyms("a", 2)?

Comment: Yes, see output above.

Comment: What else did you change? When I run the same code but importing from `ml` I get an error: AttributeError: 'Word2VecModel' object has no attribute 'getVectors'

Comment: I followed your suggestion to import from pyspark.ml.feature instead of pyspark.mllib.feature. Apparently, that was enough to get the code to work for you but it still does not work for me. Did you make any other changes to what I originally posted? If not, then I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94041/discussion-between-achampion-and-evan-zamir).